# How to correctly validate checklist field in laravel backpack?

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I created a "checklist" field with the following definition:

```
$this->crud->addField(
                [   // Checklist
                    'label'     => '<b>IDIOMAS</b>',
                    'type'      => 'checklist',
                    'name'      => 'idiomas',
                    'entity'    => 'idiomas',
                    'attribute' => 'titulo',
                    'model'     => "App\Models\Idioma",
                    'pivot'     => false,
                    'number_of_columns' => 3,
                    'wrapper' => [
                        'class' => 'form-group col-md-6',
                    ],
                    'tab' => 'HABILIDADES',
                ]
            );
```

I tried to validate with the following rules:

```
'idiomas' => 'required|array|min:1',
//'idiomas.*' => 'required|integer|exists:idiomas,id',
```

With the intention of forcing at least some element to be required. I did a lot of tests, the first one was just to use the "required" option, but nothing worked.

Reviewing the form that prints in html, I see that at the end there is a hidden field as follows:

```
<input type="hidden" value="[]" name="idiomas">
```

So for validation we receive "[]" which is NOT an array and cannot be validated that way. Shouldn't it be an array that you send? Because now it is a string of 2 characters that skips the validation of "required".
For the moment what I did was to set the rule:

```
'idiomas' => 'required|min:3'
```

And change the validation message with:

```
'idiomas.min' => 'Debe seleccionar al menos un elemento'
```

But I was left with the doubt: Is there a better way?

Is the way Backpack Laravel returns the value to validate correct?

Should it be an array?

Comment: If you want to actually post an array, the form element should be named ending with `[]` at the end. Posting the actual HTML might shed more light on things. But are you sure this isn't supposed to post JSON or something?

Comment: In this case I am using the "checklist" field from backpack for Laravel. 
https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/6.x/crud-fields#checklist-1
So it is a component that prints a specific html and my main intention with these questions is to know if what the component delivers is correct or they have missed the correct way, to report it. Or if with what it delivers, I am validating correctly or is there a better way to validate it.

Comment: Well I am not familiar with Backpack, but `[]` is a valid JSON string for an array; what is the value of the hidden element after making selections? Perhaps you just need to parse the JSON before doing validation?

Comment: You are right, although it seems obvious I had not seen it that way. The content is a valid json as an array. That is, if none of the checkboxes are selected it returns "[]". And depending on the selected elements it returns "[1]" or "[2,3]". If they are newly selected (new): "["4", "5"]". I guess the approach of writing my own rule and validating what is received as a json, passing it to an array and thus determining the minimum number of elements I require from that array, is more appropriate. I got stuck trying to forcefully use one of the validation rules that Laravel already has.

Comment: I don't know, but maybe the component should return a value that works directly with "required". 
https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#rule-required
That is to say, that with that rule it automatically validates that it is required to select an element. 
It would be interesting to have the opinion of someone from backpack to know what are the reasons and how they propose the validation.

Comment: Just use the `FormRequest::prepareForValidation()` method and replace the input value with it's `json_decode()` contents. Then validate as usual.

Comment: Thank you very much, for me this answers my questions. If you want to put it as an answer, for me it clarifies and teaches how is the right way to handle this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Backpack, but if the hidden element's value at initialization is `[]` I'm willing to bet it posts its data as a JSON string. To validate it, you'd need to decode the JSON first and then add it back into the request object. Here's my suggestion:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class MyRequest extends FormRequest
{
    protected function prepareForValidation(): void
    {
        // could also use $this->replace() if desired
        $this->merge([
            "idiomas_data" => json_decode($this->idiomas),
        ]);
    }

    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            "idiomas_data" => ["required", "array", "min:1"],
            "idiomas_data.*" => ["integer", "exists:idiomas"],
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to validate at least 1 element, can use something like this:

```
return [
        'idiomas' => [
            'required',
            'string',
            'json',
            function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
                $elementsArray = json_decode($value, true);

                if (empty($elementsArray)) {
                    $fail('The '.$attribute.' must contain at least one element.');
                }
            },
        ],
    ];
```

Cheers.